# Relay access denied only for one machine?

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, sles

So i have a postfix relay that works for my first machine (SLE12 SP5) but not for my second one (SLE12 SP4).
Both machines are in the same domain, they are also in the same local network and same subnet.

The `/etc/hosts` file are both filled with the relay :

```
(postfix's ip)   postfix.local-domain.com   postfix   external-domain.com
```

The `resolv.conf` file are both filled with the right domain :

```
domain local-domain.com
search local-domain.com
```

Both have default route through the local network :

```
ip route show
default via (subnet gateway) dev eth0
(subnet ip/mask) dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src (machine's ip)
```

Here is the command i'm using :

```
echo "This is first machine" | mailx -s "This is Subject" -S smtp="postfix" -v my.email@external-domain.com
```

Result on the first machine :

```
Resolving host postfix . . . done.
Connecting to (postfix's ip):smtp . . . connected.
220 postfix.local-domain.com ESMTP Postfix
>>> HELO firstmachine.local-domain.com
250 postfix.local-domain.com
>>> MAIL FROM:<root@firstmachine.local-domain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
>>> RCPT TO:<my.email@external-domain.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
>>> DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
>>> .
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6B5954D443
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Same command on the second machine :

```
echo "This is second machine" | mailx -s "This is Subject" -S smtp="postfix" -v my.email@external-domain.com
```

Result on the second machine :

```
Resolving host postfix . . . done.
Connecting to (postfix's ip):smtp . . . connected.
220 postfix.local-domain.com ESMTP Postfix
>>> HELO secondmachine.local-domain.com
250 postfix.local-domain.com
>>> MAIL FROM:<root@secondmachine.local-domain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
>>> RCPT TO:<my.email@external-domain.com>
554 5.7.1 <my.email@external-domain.com>: Relay access denied
smtp-server: 554 5.7.1 <my.email@external-domain.com>: Relay access denied
"/root/dead.letter" 11/361
. . . message not sent.
```

The content of /root/dead.letter file :

```
This is second machine
Date: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 11:34:01 +0200
From: root@secondmachine.local-domain.com
To: my.email@external-domain.com
Subject: This is Subject
Message-ID: <60d30009.yXYpk0su5Y1hKjCx%root@secondmachine.localdomain.com>
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Am i missing something here ? I'm still learning so feel free to share your knowledge !

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own post in case someone is in the same situation.

So i found out that there is a file allowing machines to connect or not.

In the `main.cf` file :

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/maps/access_client
```

In the `/etc/postfix/maps/access_client` file :

```
(second machine's ip)     OK
```

Then type this command :

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/maps/access_client
```

Then restart the postfix service :

```
service postfix restart
```

Worked for me